# onclick event to happen here before continuing in while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want an onclick event to happen before continuing in while loop in javascript.

please help..

This code is part of playing cards...There is 4 players and one of them is the user. I want to wait till the user puts the card before continuing and user can click on any card he likes..

```
while(k<4){
    var nextplayer=playerobj[(i+1)%4];
if(((i+1)%4)==0){ //this is the user
    comment.innerHTML="please put the card player 0";
    i++;k++;
```

// I want an onclick event to happen here before continuing and the onclick event can happen on any of the cards(elements)...

```
}
else{ //put cards by this function
var c=nextplayer.getCard(cardontable[0].type,cardontable[0].value);
i++;k++;
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. Question is not clear as to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $('#Id').click();
```

or

```
 $('#Id').trigger("click");
```

Comment: the question has no jQuery tag.